# excel vba - how to make this a single loop

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop, macros

I have a section of code containing 3 for loops. I want to figure out a way, probably by way of using arrays, to make this one single loop. The way the data is pieced together, columns 4,5,6 are not populating data. It works out that the data should just be what is populated 1 row above. So this code works just fine, I am just looking for a more efficient way of coding it. Thanks!

```
For i = 2 To erow
    If currentSht.Cells(i, 4).Value = "" Then
        currentSht.Cells(i, 4).Value = currentSht.Cells(i - 1, 4).Value
    End If
Next i

For i = 2 To erow
    If currentSht.Cells(i, 5).Value = "" Then
        currentSht.Cells(i, 5).Value = currentSht.Cells(i - 1, 5).Value
    End If
Next i

For i = 2 To erow
    If currentSht.Cells(i, 6).Value = "" Then
        currentSht.Cells(i, 6).Value = currentSht.Cells(i - 1, 6).Value
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: Put it all inside one loop?

Comment: question better suited for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) (*as long as it works, as you state it does)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about multiple For's

```
For i = 2 To erow
    For j = 4 to 6
         If currentSht.Cells(i, j).Value = "" Then
              currentSht.Cells(i, j).Value = currentSht.Cells(i - 1, j).Value
         End If
    Next j
Next i
```

Answer (score 2):

Put all three IFs in one loop:

```
For i = 2 To erow
    If currentSht.Cells(i, 4).Value = "" Then
        currentSht.Cells(i, 4).Value = currentSht.Cells(i - 1, 4).Value
    End If
    If currentSht.Cells(i, 5).Value = "" Then
        currentSht.Cells(i, 5).Value = currentSht.Cells(i - 1, 5).Value
    End If
    If currentSht.Cells(i, 6).Value = "" Then
        currentSht.Cells(i, 6).Value = currentSht.Cells(i - 1, 6).Value
    End If
Next i
```